# Whose info should I write in the DS-260 "Sign and Submit" page?

Tags: usa, visa, greencard

My father has filled my DS-260 form and now we are stuck in the "Sign and Submit" page, where it asks for the case number and passport number. We have one case number of course, but which passport's number should we enter, mine or his? **The form is mine but he is the one who filled it.**

EDIT: this are the fields I am referring to:

[image]

Comment: In this sample DS-260: travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/DS-260-Exemplar.pdf, the "Sign and Submit" page contains a box in which information about the "preparer," the person who filled in the application, should be added. On the other hand, the next page, titled "E-Signature," also contains a request for case number and passport number, but appears immediately after language affirming that the information to be entered on the "E-Signature" page is for the "undersigned applicant." Which box(es) on which page are you asking about?

Comment: I have edited my question and included the fields.

Comment: Thank you for editing your question to include more information.

Answer (score 1):

The DS-260 presented in the question does not exactly track the appearance of the [DS-260 exemplar cited in the comments](http://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/DS-260-Exemplar.pdf).

The DS-260 presented in the question, however, contains a reference to the signer's Selective Service System form DS-1810. This form refers to the SSS status of the applicant or the applicant's family members who are included in the application and will be entering the United States. It does not (necessarily) refer to the "preparer" of the application.

Therefore, the signature fields you reference should be completed with the applicant's passport number. "The form is mine" wording in the question suggests the son (the writer of the question) is the applicant. If that's correct, then the son's passport number should be entered.

Comment: Yes, I am the applicant corresponding to the form in question but my father is the main applicant. A lot of thanks for your time!

Comment: Made sense until you said you are the applicant in this form, but your father is the "main applicant." Whose information (yours or your father's) fills the whole rest of the form? That person is the applicant whose passport number should be inserted at this point.

Comment: This is now clear. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Good luck to you!